# disabling Internet Explorer properties in an aspx page

Tags: asp.net

Can I disable all properties of an Internet Explorer when it opens a particular page called "help.aspx".
I want that no option should be displayed on that page,just the content of the page which include the image of a person.

can anybody plzz help me.?

Comment: What "options" or "properties" are you trying to disable? Menu options? It sounds like you're trying to do something "evil" and against the user's wishes, so it's unlikely that what you're trying to do is possible in any supported or appropriate way.

Comment: no no ..its not evil. i just want to display a page with no menu bar,no addressbar,no standard button,so that i should have a secure page .

Comment: Not sure what you mean by secure. A user could still download the image on the page if they wanted to.

Comment: As Raj asks, how would this make a page more secure? What are you trying to protect against? Let's start with the actual problem instead of looking at how to implement a particular solution.

Comment: i just want that the user cant have an option of going to back page and cant access the url of that page...

Comment: I suppose we might have different definitions of "evil." What if the user is using Firefox or Chrome? You still haven't told us what exactly you're trying to protect. I'm hesitant to offer a solution just yet because depending on exactly *why* you're trying to protected something there will be different solutions. What purpose does hiding the URL serve? I can run Fiddler and see all the URLs going through the browser as well as the content being served. Not even HTTPS will protect against that.

Comment: leave that....what actually i am doing is i am displaying a report in the reportviewer using a asp page.In that report i created a page which displays list of all the employees from a database.Now I want that when i click on that name of any employee,it should display d image of that employee on a pop-up window.

i was not able to sole that problem so i thought of a page with no menu and address bar to display a image.

can anybody help me with that popup thing?
plzzz...

thanxxx

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest comment I can offer up a different solution that will work cross-browser:

Instead of opening a new browser window, why not use an in-page popup? For example, the [jQuery UI dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) is super easy to use. You can pop up the dialog with an image and any other text that you might want. The benefit of doing this in-page is that the URL in the address bar won't change, which seems to be one of your requirements. It also won't have any new menu bar - just the main window's menu bar.

In terms of security, you have still yet to describe the exact security requirements. If the images are meant to be secure then the only truly secure option is to never display them. I can always use the camera built in to my smart phone to take a picture of the computer monitor and "steal" the image - you can't prevent that with any kind of technological solution.